# React-Native cannot run project if I am not Sudo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, terminal, jsx

I am unable to run react-native project with the code `react-native run-android`. I am getting the following error

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

But it runs if I run it as root `sudo react-native run-andoid'.

How can I make the project run without being root??

Answer (score 3):

I found out from reading the [post](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92) by Medium that u have to give permission to every folder explicitly when u encounter a permission issue when installing react native and realated tools, so that u can run the app without being sudo. Otherwise the files installed by sudo can only be run as sudo.

Use the below command to give access to the current user for that specific folder

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Documents/Myapplicationfolder
```